# XSL for-each and value-of

Tags: xslt, foreach, value-of

Given the xml:

```
<element>text</element>
...
<element>text</element>
```

And xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

What do I need to put inside the for-each loop to access the text? There doesn't seem to be a corresponding `xsl:value-of` because `select=""`, `select="/"`, and `select="element"` are all wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: also select="text()" as I just found in the xpath recommendation

Comment: @Sandy The difference is this: `.` refers to the current node (`<element>`) itself. The `value-of` a node is its entire text contents (including the text of any descendant nodes!). `text()` only refers to the *direct children* of the current node that are text nodes (this excludes any descendant nodes!). In your case, this makes no actual difference. There are cases where it does.